# extract data from xml file CI

Tags: xml, codeigniter

i have an input form:

```
<?php 
echo form_open('site/getFeed');
echo form_input('feed_url','Please insert your feed url');
echo form_submit('submit','Add');
```

controller:

```
function getFeed() {

    $content = file_get_contents($this->input->post('feed_url'));
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);    
    foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
        $feeds[] = array(
                        'title' => (string)$entry->title,
                        'url' => (string)$entry->link,
                        'username' => $this->session->userdata('username'));}
        $this->load->model('membership_model');
        $this->membership_model->insert_feeds($feeds);
```

the function insert in my table the title, url, username. My question is why it not insert the correct link  Ex. Instead of this`http://feeds.reuters.com/~r/news/artsculture/~3/Vhga7xMFmnI/us-usa-bush-art-idUSBREA1O0WR20140225` is insert me this for all titles:`http://feeds.reuters.com/` .
Here is the source of page from i extract data: `view-source:http://feeds.reuters.com/news/artsculture`.

Comment: what is the url field length in db?

Comment: it was the length. Thanks!

Comment: Oh.. Fixed your problem?

Comment: @user3313651 if that fixed the problem, then accept his comment as the answer please.